# How do I revert GCC version from 4.8.3 to 4.8.2?

Tags: linux, gcc, centos

I accidentally updated the GCC version on a machine at work. We work with a very specific setup that requires GCC 4.8.2, so I must revert the GCC update. I'm running on CentOS 7.

Comment: It is not very easy task. I think you need build all libraries in system using GCC 4.8.2, that you plan to use.

Comment: How did you update your GCC? Using package manager?

Comment: If the repositories still have the previous RPM (and many should) you can try `yum downgrade gcc-4.8.2`. You might need to point back at a `7.0` repository for this though.

Comment: yum supports undo command, so you can undo your update, if you use yum for GCC update

Comment: @gomons I think so. I was restarting my computer so I clicked "restart and update packages".

Comment: @gomons, there's no need to rebuild anything.

Comment: @Jonathan Wakely, you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many hours of experimentation, this is the solution that I found:

The solution is to install gcc-4.8.2 from a .rpm file. Luckily, it looks like yum caches previous rpm files.

I went to `/var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/updates/packages` and I found a bunch of .rpm packages, including the gcc-4.8.2 rpm file!

I tried to run `sudo yum localinstall gcc-4.8.2-16.2.el7_0.x86_64.rpm`, however it said that some of its dependencies were the wrong version.

To fix this, I called `sudo yum remove` on the problematic dependencies, namely libgomp and cpp. I then called `sudo yum localinstall` for both of the packages, using their 4.8.2 .rpm files that were in the yum cache directory.

I then ran `sudo yum localinstall gcc-4.8.2-16.2.el7_0.x86_64.rpm` again, and it was successful!

Answer (score 3):

Print yum history and find unnecessary update:

```
yum history
```

It prints something like:

```
ID     | Login user               | Date and time    | Action(s)      | Altered
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     8 | root <root>              | 2011-10-03 14:40 | Install        |    1   
     7 | root <root>              | 2011-09-21 04:24 | Install        |    1 ##
     6 | root <root>              | 2011-09-21 04:23 | Install        |    1 ##
     5 | root <root>              | 2011-09-16 13:35 | Install        |    1   
     4 | root <root>              | 2011-09-16 13:33 | Erase          |    1   
     3 | root <root>              | 2011-09-14 14:36 | Install        |    1   
     2 | root <root>              | 2011-09-12 15:48 | I, U           |   80   
     1 | System <unset>           | 2011-09-12 14:57 | Install        | 1025
```

Than undo it:

```
yum history undo 8
```

Undo command can fail if old packages are not in repo anymore, so you can try to include archive repo.

Comment: And do not forgot make backup of your system

Comment: I ran your suggestion and it said "failed to downgrade ...". I'm still investigating why it says that. It's possibly because yum wasn't done completing the update, so I will try to run `sudo yum-complete-transaction --cleanup-only` and then call the `history undo` command again.

Comment: Are old packages still in repo?

Comment: It is possible, that you should include archive repos for undo

Comment: How can I do that? I'm sorry I don't know what you mean by repo!

Comment: repo - repository, all packages that you install reside in repository. When you tries undo, new installed packages uninstalled and old packages installed from repository. But if repository does'n contain old package anymore, it can't be intalled.

Comment: Check whether `gcc-4.8.2` is still in repository you are using.

Comment: You can try @Etan Reisner suggestion `yum downgrade gcc-4.8.2`